# Postgresql - can't load csv file into table

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import, copy

I'm trying to load a few csv files into several postgresql tables but none of them are working and generating a variety of errors.

The files are public and located here:

http://www.kaggle.com/c/march-machine-learning-mania-2015/data

I'm using pgAdmin version 1.20.0 with psql 9.4.0 on a Windows 8 machine.

Here are the things I've tried so far:

I'm using pgAdmin and can create the schema and table.

I then right click on the table, open the import tool, choose the file, set the format to csv, click the header check box, set the delimiter to ',' and click 'Import', and get an error that there is extra data after the last expected column.

Next, I tried using the command line with this:

```
copy marchmad.regular_season_compact_results FROM 'C:/data/regular_season_compact_results.csv' CSV HEADER delimiter ',' null '\N';
```

and get this error message:

```
ERROR: could not open file "C:/data/regular_season_compact_results.csv" for reading: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

Next, I try putting a '\' in front like this:

```
\copy marchmad.regular_season_compact_results FROM 'C:/data/regular_season_compact_results.csv' CSV HEADER delimiter ',' null '\N';
```

and get this error message:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Any suggestions for how to make this work?

Comment: in pdAdmin, did you look at the 'columns to import tab' to ensure that there were the same number of columns in your csv data as well as the table you created?  Did the columns that you created line up with the csv (types and location)?

Comment: @ivan7707: just realized I needed to define columns before using the import tool.  Assumed it was similar to sql server import wizard and it would handle column definition for me.

Answer (score 4):

In *pgAdmin*, you can only use `copy`, which is a server-side *SQL* command, so permissions for the file are from a server perspective, even if the server is on *localhost*.

The error you're getting from that command suggests that the *Postgres* **server** doesn't have permission to access the *CSV* file. It may be that you're running the server as another user, say, *postgres*, and the CSV can't be accessed by it. If you adjust the permissions such that the user your server is running as can access the *CSV* file and the directory that it's in, I would expect it to work.

The `\copy` command doesn't work because that's a special *psql* command usable in the *psql* terminal. Since it operates on the **client** side, it will generally be running under your user.  Therefore, it's likely to be the same user as the one that downloaded the *CSV*, and thus will have access.

You can try using the [*psql*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) terminal if you want to try it that way. Generally I prefer using *psql* for dealing with copying files, since that way it's always locally focused in terms of file/permissions, and therefore I can easily copy files to even remote servers without needing to be concerned about special access on the server's file system.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the file regular_season_compact_results.csv, there is a blank line. That might be the problem giving you the error.

Comment: I tried removing the last line and same issues remain.

Comment: If you could, post your table structure.  Its probably Ok, but debuggers like me like to see everything we can.  I would make a temp file with just the header and part of the data.  It might import, might not. Then add more of the data. The idea is to find what line of data causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the file that you want to import needs permission, for that go to security section from proprieties and click add in the white text part write 'Everyone'
be sure that the read and execute check box checked!

Comment: Note that this is very insecure! Please check which account needs the particular read permissions and give it ```read``` only!